# how to pass Integer to another Activity on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-intent

I am developing simple game on android studio, where you need to identify the given image. each image has 40 points but every time you answer it wrong, your 40 points will be deducted by 10 points. The points will be accumulated until you finish identify the 10 picture. My problem is, I don't know how to pass the points to another activity so that I can add it. here's my Java code.. PS. sorry I am so new in android studio and also in StackOverflow, I don't know how to compose a question.

```
    public void onClickSubmit (View view) {

        answer = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAnswer);
        tvResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultLabel);

        if (answer.getText().toString().equals("apple")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, appleTrivia.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            tvResult.setText("Good eye sight");
            tvResult.setTextColor(0xFF00FF00);
            timer.cancel();
            totalScorePoints = scorePoints;

            String result = String.valueOf(totalScorePoints);
            pointsLabel.setText("Score: " + result);
            answer.setText("");



        } else {
            tvResult.setText("No no no. try again.");
            tvResult.setTextColor(0xFFFF0011);
            answer.setText("");
            scorePoints = scorePoints - minusPoint;
            totalScorePoints = scorePoints;
            String result = String.valueOf(totalScorePoints);
            pointsLabel.setText("Score: " + result);
```

How can I pass the  totalScorePoint to my second activity so that the points from first activity will be added to the points of second activity. tnx to all who will response to my noob problem ^_^ This is my second activity.`enter code here
  public void onClickSubmit (View view) {

```
    answer = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAnswer);
    tvResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultLabel);

    if (answer.getText().toString().equals("cherry")) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, cherryTrivia.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        tvResult.setText("Good eye sight");
        tvResult.setTextColor(0xFF00FF00);
        timer.cancel();

        totalScorePoints = scorePoints;

        String result = String.valueOf(totalScorePoints);
        pointsLabel.setText("Score: " + result);
        answer.setText("");
    } else {
        tvResult.setText("No no no. try again.");
        tvResult.setTextColor(0xFFFF0011);
        answer.setText("");
        scorePoints = scorePoints - minusPoint;
        totalScorePoints = scorePoints;
        String result = String.valueOf(totalScorePoints);
        pointsLabel.setText("Score: " + result);



    }
}
}


 <!-- end snippet -->
```

Comment: You have to use a Bundle.

http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/os/android-bundle-example/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the sending side:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, cherryTrivia.class);
intent.putExtra( "points", scorePoints );
startActivity(intent);
```

On the receiving side:

```
getIntent().getIntExtra( "points", 0 );
```

Comment: okay sir thanks for responding on my problem. i'll try to add it on my code, I hope i can able to determine where i will insert it, I am really a newbie in this stuff. ^_^

Comment: Sir? I don't know what's wrong on it, its not working on me, maybe i putted it in the wrong why. here's what i did.                                     Intent intent = new Intent(this, cherryTrivia.class);
intent.putExtra( "points", scorePoints );
startActivity(intent); and on my second activity I putted it this way.  Intent intent = new Intent(this, cherryTrivia.class);
            getIntent().getIntExtra( "points", 0 );
            startActivity(intent);                                                                                                           didi I done it wrong sir?

Comment: @HerbertWillkomm in second Activity you have to do only this : `int var = getIntent().getIntExtra( "points", 0 );` that's all you will get value in `var`.